# Intellij built in Application Server

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, application-server

I was wondering if IntelliJ has a built in Application Server (like Tomcat) that I can use without having to download Tomcat directly?

Right now when I go to `Run | Edit Configurations, Defaults, Tomcat Server, Local`, it asks me to specify the Tomcat home directory.

Previously I had used myEclipse and it came packaged with a Tomcat so I would be suprised if the ultimate version of IntelliJ does not have this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellij does not include built in application server. It has simple web server they refer to as Webstorm. However it is not application server.

Here is excellent resource (official docs) for working with application servers in intellij which you may find to be useful including tips on integrating it IDE via plugins etc:
[Working with Application Servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-application-servers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download an application server manually.

Or you could use a Maven/Gradle dependency to start Tomcat programmaticly from the Main method, or a plugin for starting it via command line e.g. `mvn tomcat:run`.